# C# class to check if files exists in folder

Tags: c#, class

I am very new to C# and i have written the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace PrinterManager
{
    class CheckFilesExist
    {
        public class CheckFilesExist
        {
            public static bool check(bool isThere)
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\temp");
                FileInfo[] TXTFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xml");
                if (TXTFiles.Length == 0)
                {
                    return isThere;
                }
                foreach (var fi in TXTFiles)
                    //return (fi.Exists);
                    return (fi.Exists);

                    return check;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

It should check the directory for *.xml files and add them to an array. If it doesnt find any files then it should return false. It will go through the array and return true or false based on "check".

But i am getting the following error:

> Cannot convert method group 'check' to non-delegate type 'bool'. Did
>   you intend to invoke the method?

It doesnt seem to like, "return check;" at the end.

I basically want to return a check to see if files exists in the folder. 
Any ideas why mine isnt working?

Thanks

Comment: That title does not seem to have anything to do with the actual question.

Comment: what is check ? Why do you have a return (fi.exist) and return check ? Return after a return does not work ? Why do you need to loop thru the array ? Why can't you just use return true and return false instead of using those variables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't like `return check;` at the end - what did you want it to do? Your *method* is `check` - so "return true or false based on `check`" doesn't really make sense. Did you actually *mean* to return `isThere` instead?

It's not clear what the parameter is even really meant to be there for, to be honest... and if you've asked a `DirectoryInfo` for the files in that directory, I'd personally expect them to exist - otherwise why would they be returned?

Oh, and your directory name contains a tab where I suspect you actually want a backslash followed by a `t`.

I suspect your method would be better as:

```
public static bool TempDirectoryContainsXmlFiles()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
    return di.GetFiles("*.xml").Length > 0; 
}
```

or using LINQ for clarity:

```
public static bool TempDirectoryContainsXmlFiles()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
    return di.GetFiles("*.xml").Any();
}
```

(You can use [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) as shown by BrokenGlass which is more efficient for a large directory, but it's only available in .NET 4 and upwards.)

Comment: oh excellent.. so i dont need to build a class? i can just call it with a method on my form?

Comment: @PD24: Yes. There's no need for a separate class here.

Comment: in which scenario would i need a seperate class? i am building a print manager which will parse the file names GUID id and compare it with the file upload date time from the database. Would i need a class to do these checks?

Comment: @PD24: Ideally you should be thinking in terms of *objects* of different classes - there's relatively little point in creating a new class for a static method, unless it's going to be used from several other classes and you want one central place for it. You'd normally create a class to encapsulate a set of *state* information and behaviour which acts on that state. You *could* potentially create a class for the information you're talking about, but it's not really clear that it would be worthwhile in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this.. i am going to select your answer as the my prefered one. Thank you sooo much. :) I have learned alot.

Comment: what would be the best way to show that a txt file exists in the directory? do i put messagebox.show di.GetFiles??

Answer (score 4):

You can make a one-liner out of your method:

```
return new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp").EnumerateFiles("*.xml").Any();
```

Note that you are either have to use a literal string (prefixed by `@`) or properly escape the directory name, i.e. `"C:\\temp"`.

Answer (score 1):

try like this....

```
private static bool Check_file_Existence(string sFileName)
{
    try
    {
       return File.Exists(sFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, the problem as to be with the fact of your "check" variable having the same name as your function...